# c# Bootstrap using if else for eval() in a repeater

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap-3, repeater

```
<asp:Button ID="btnbl" runat="server" Text="Block" 
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")+","+ Eval("block")%>'  
CommandName="changebutton1" class="btn btn-primary btn-purple" />
```

Is there somewhere to make if eval("block") == 1, change classs into class="btn btn-primary btn-purple disabled"?

Answer (score 0):

Try using conditional operator `?:` here like `class='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("block")) == 1? "btn btn-primary btn-purple disabled" : "btn btn-primary btn-purple"%>'`

Ex -

```
<asp:Button ID="btnbl" runat="server" Text="Block" 
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")+","+ Eval("block")%>'  
CommandName="changebutton1" class='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("block")) == 1? "btn btn-primary btn-purple disabled" : "btn btn-primary btn-purple"%>' />
```

see is it helping

Comment: there is error operator == cannot be applied to operands of type object to int

Comment: @FundverseOng Ive edited my answer by converting the object to int before comparing .Check it now